# Avoid caching images for GET requests in Spring MVC

Tags: java, internet-explorer, spring-mvc

There is functionality to upload a picture to web page. It is stored on file system. When upload another picture instead of current it overrides it with the same name. And Internet Explorer 8 displays the old one. After ctrl+r new one is displayed. I have added to my get method

```
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

In IE8 it doesn't help. In google chrome it works perfectly.

Comment: add some random parameter in your GET request. It will make every request as unique request and the request will not cache. something like http://ur_url:port/someuri?param1=value1&uniqueValue={System.currentTimeMillis()}  ...

Comment: It doesn't work for images.